# how get json result in view without using Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i want to get JsonResult of Action in my view without using Ajax

**Action Is**

```
public JsonResult CourceDetails()
    {
       var result= ("_C");
       return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**view is**

```
  @{
        ViewBag.Title = "CourceDetails";
    }

          <h2>CourceDetails</h2>
          <div>

         </div>
```

Comment: how you will use it on,front end without ajax? ?

Comment: is it possible or not